# Spark - Flatten Array of Structs using flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a df with schema -

```
root
 |-- arrayCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- email: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- qty: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rqty: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sqty: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- start: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- otherId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- primarykey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- runtime: string (nullable = true)
```

I don't want to use `explode` as its extremely slow and wanted to try `flapMap` instead.

I tried doing -

```
val ds = df1.as[(Array[StructType], String, String)]
ds.flatMap{ case(x, y, z) => x.map((_, y, z))}.toDF()
```

This gives me error -

`scala.MatchError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`

How do I flatten arrayCol?

Sample data -

```
{
"primaryKeys":"sfdfrdsdjn",
"runtime":"2020-10-31T13:01:04.813Z",
"arrayCol":[{"id":"qwerty","id1":"dsfdsfdsf","window":{"start":"2020-11-01T10:30:00Z","end":"2020-11-01T12:30:00Z"}, "email":[],"id2":"sdfsdfsdPuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g","rqty":3,"sqty":3,"qty":3,"otherId":null}]
}
```

Expected Output -

```
primaryKey  runtime  arrayCol
sfdfrdsdjn   2020-10-31T13:01:04.813Z  {"id":"qwerty","id1":"dsfdsfdsf","window":{"start":"2020-11-01T10:30:00Z","end":"2020-11-01T12:30:00Z"}, "email":[],"id2":"sdfsdfsdPuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g","rqty":3,"sqty":3,"qty":3,"otherId":null}
```

I want one row for every element in arrayCol. Just like `explode(arrayCol)`

Comment: spark version ? also post sample data for testing ?

Comment: Spark version - Spark 2.4

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: expected output ??

Comment: Added expected output.

Comment: I think the sample data and the Schema does not match. when I read the sample data and printschema for that it is different that what you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Remember when using spark with scala, [always try to use the Dataset API as often as possible](https://databricks.com/fr/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html). This not only increases readeability, but helps solve these type of issues very quickly.

```
case class ArrayColWindow(end:String,start:String)
case class ArrayCol(id:String,email:Seq[String], qty:Long,rqty:Long,pids:Seq[String],
                    sqty:Long,id1:String,id2:String,window:ArrayColWindow, otherId:String)

case class FullArrayCols(arrayCol:Seq[ArrayCol],primarykey:String,runtime:String)

val inputTest = List(
          FullArrayCols(Seq(ArrayCol("qwerty", Seq(), 3, 3, Seq(), 3, "dsfdsfdsf", "sdfsdfsdPuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g",
            ArrayColWindow("2020-11-01T10:30:00Z", "2020-11-01T12:30:00Z"), null)),
            "sfdfrdsdjn", "2020-10-31T13:01:04.813Z")
        ).toDS()
    
val output = inputTest.as[(Seq[ArrayCol],String,String)].flatMap{ case(x, y, z) => x.map((_, y, z))}
output.show(truncate=false)
```

Comment: So is there a way to do this without declaring class ArrayCol? It is dynamic and I can't hardcode it in such way. I just want every struct of arrayCol to be a new row.

Answer (score 0):

you could just change

```
val ds = df1.as[(Array[StructType], String, String)]
```

to

```
val ds = df1.as[(Array[String], String, String)]
```

and you can get rid of the error and see the output you want.

Comment: I want a struct in every row not a string. arrayCol is array of structs and not string.